# SQL - Best practice for handling mass arbitrary data

Tags: t-sql

I have a massive delimited file and many normalized tables to input the data. Is there a best practice for bringing in the data and inserting the data into its proper fields and tables?

For instance, right now I've created a temp table that holds all the arbitrary data. Some logic runs against each row to determine what values will be going in to what table. Without too much specifics the part that concerns me looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (
    (SELECT TOP 1 field1 FROM #tmpTable),
    (SELECT TOP 1 field30 FROM #tmpTable),
    (SELECT TOP 1 field2 FROM #tmpTable),
    ...
    (SELECT TOP 1 field4 FROM #tmpTable))
```

With that, my questions are: Is it reasonable to be using a temp table for this purpose? And is it poor practice to use these SELECT statements so liberally like this? It feels sort of hacky, are there a better ways to handle mass data importing and separation like this?

Comment: If possible, you may want to supply some sample data that you are attempting to parse.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should try SSIS.

[SSIS How to Create an ETL Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx)

[image]

Comment: SSIS is the first thing popped into my mind too.